# Finding related mongodb document using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning how to use MongDB using the Mongoose module in my NodeJS project.

I have a requirement whereby I have a collection of Roller Coasters and each Roller Coaster has a number of Coaster Reviews, so its like a one to many type relationship, each individual Roller Coaster has many Coaster Reviews.

In learning about creating a Mongoose schema I added the Roller Coasters ID to the Coaster Reviews schema, so that each review that gets created has a link to its Roller Coaster via the ID.

Here is the Roller Coaster Schema:

```
/**
 * Rollercoaster Schema
 */
var RollercoasterSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Rollercoaster name',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

Here is the Coaster Review schema:

```
/**
 * Coasterreview Schema
 */
var CoasterreviewSchema = new Schema({
    review: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Coasterreview review',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    rollercoaster: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Rollercoaster'
    }
});
```

This Schema works fine when I get a list of the Coaster Reviews and then populate the Roller Coaster.

However I also have a requirement to get a list of the Roller Coasters and also the Coaster Reviews related to each Roller Coaster if any. I have a limited knowledge of how best to do this and my current approach would mean that I would need to get the list of Roller Coasters and then loop through this list and then have to again go to the database for each Roller Coaster to fetch the list of Coaster Reviews for each Roller Coaster, this to me doesn't seem correct, here is pseudo code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Rollercoaster = mongoose.model('Rollercoaster'),
    CoasterReview = mongoose.model('Coasterreview');


Rollercoaster.find().sort('-created').exec(function(err, rollercoasters) {
        if (err) {
            return 'Error';
        } else {
            //Need to loop through the RollerCoasters from the result
            //In each loop need to use CoasterReview.find to get the coaster reviews for each roller coaster
            //This will result in a lot of calls to the DB, there must be a better way to do this?
            rollercoasters.forEach(function(coaster){
                CoasterReview.find().sort('-created').exec(function(err, reviews) {
                    //Add the list of reviews to the rollercoaster here
                    //This is async code so how do I handle this correctly, this current manner doesn't seem to be the correct way
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

So my problem is that my approach is correct for my getting lists of my Coaster Reviews but seems to be a bit inefficient for getting lists of the Roller Coasters documents and their related Coaster Review documents, can anyone help point me in the right direction as to how best to do this with Mongoose?

**EDIT:**

Using Mi Ke Bu's code has got me a little closer, here is the code:

```
Rollercoaster.find(query).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').populate('themepark').exec(function(err, rollercoasters) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            //list of ids
            var rcIds = rollercoasters.map(function(el){return el._id;});
            //select all reviews with 'rollercoaster' = any _id from list
            CoasterReview
                .find({'rollercoaster':{$in:rcIds}}).sort('-created').exec(function(err, reviews) {
                    //res.jsonp(rollercoasters);
                    res.jsonp(reviews);
                });
        }
    });
```

However this just gives me the list of Roller Coasters and the list of Coaster Reviews separately, as in there is no link between the Roller Coaster and its Coaster Reviews in what is returned, I would have to loop through the arrays here and try to match up the Coaster Reviews with each Roller Coaster, is there a way to avoid this using Mongoose and get it to return something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "55c2106227f2a878292a564d",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2015-08-05T13:32:18.473Z",
    "name": "Jurassic Park : The Ride",
    coasterreviews: [
    {
      "_id": "55dcbd9662a5516c39d27946",
      "rollercoaster": "55c2106227f2a878292a564d",
      "__v": 0,
      "created": "2015-08-25T19:10:14.392Z",
      "review": "The theming is fantastic"
    },
    {
        "_id": "55d8bb292d03db3c1310d465",
        "rollercoaster": "55c2106227f2a878292a564d",
        "__v": 0,
        "created": "2015-08-22T18:10:49.201Z",
        "review": "Woah what a ride, really thrilling and a great experience."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "55c20f0f27f2a878292a564c",
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2015-08-05T13:26:39.055Z",
    "name": "Dragon Challenge : Hungarian Horntail",
    coasterreviews: [
      {
      "_id": "55d8d21908eda5a018c22ed4",
      "rollercoaster": "55c20f0f27f2a878292a564c",
      "__v": 0,
      "created": "2015-08-22T19:48:41.854Z",
      "review": "Great ride"
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
} else {
    //list of ids
    var rcIds = rollercoasters.map(function(el){return el._id;});
    //select all reviews with 'rollercoaster' = any _id from list
    CoasterReview
        .find({"rollercoaster":{$in:rcIds}})
        .sort(...)
        .exec(function(err,reviews){
            //upd start
            reviews.forEach(function(r){
                var c=rollercoaster.filter(function(el){return el._id.equals(r.rollercoaster);});
                c.coasterreviews=c.coasterreviews || [];
                c.coasterreviews.push(r);
            });
            res.jsonp(rollercoaster);
            //upd end

        });
}
```

About $in read: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: Thanks, this is closer to what I need however its not quite 100% there, with this code I get all the roller coasters and all the reviews but they are not linked. Is there a way where I get the list of Roller Coasters and then the array of Coaster Reviews is populated within that Roller Coaster document?

Comment: I have updated my question to try to explain what I mean.

Comment: Thanks  Mi Ke Bu - I am aware this is a possible solution, however I am wondering if there is a better way to do this via Mongoose, either by changing the schema or the call to the DB, this may very well be the only way to do this though?

Comment: May be you need `Model.mapReduce`?
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce

Comment: Looking into mapReduce now, one thing to note with your current code though, for some reason return el._id==r.rollercoaster; always returns false and should use the .equals  function instead

Comment: Why? Because `_id` is complex type `Schema.ObjectId`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it will only work because it is a complex type, == didn't work.

Comment: Also for some reason the coaster reviews are not getting pushed to the returned documents, as in coasterreviews is never part of the JSON that is returned from res.jsonp(rollercoasters);

Comment: But what about `===`? It will work? Then 'not push' is result of bad comparator in filter.

Comment: === did not work either, after changing it to .equals() it works, so the comparator in the filter is working but the objects are then not getting added to the JSON for some reason.